# A better way than chaining _.groupBy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, underscore.js

When I do this I get an array which stores the data as grouped by the month and day of the date but not by the year (I am doing this to get maximum, minimum, and average values for each day there is data for)

The problem is that the array stores an array of 2-3 values for that day and month within the date which is the key value. Those 2-3 indices each have an array of length one that holds a reference to an object which has the actual data point (level) I need. The object contains three attributes, date, id (which is always null), and level which is a float.

I either need to find a way so those 2-3 indices hold the object directly, or find a way that _.each can access the level.

Any thoughts?

```
var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, "date");

var groupedLevels = _.groupBy(groupedData, function (points, date) {
  var dateParsed = parseDate(date);
  var month = dateParsed.getMonth();
  var day = dateParsed.getDate();

  var monthDay = month + "-" + day; 
  return monthDay;
});

_.each(groupedLevels, function (points, date) {
  var levels = _.map(_.pluck(points, "level"), parseFloat);

  minimum.push([ date, R.min(levels) ]);
  maximum.push([ date, R.max(levels);

  var averageLevel = R.sum(levels) / levels.length;

  average.push([date, averageLevel]);
})
```

So the data, as is, which is the original input looks like this (a sample piece):

```
[ { date: "2009-01-01",
    id: null,
    level: "0.08",
  },
  // ...
]
```

Currently, groupedData is this:

```
{ "2009-01-01":
  [ { date: "2009-01-01",
      id: null,
      level: "0.08"
    }
  ],
  // ...
}
```

groupedLevels looks like this, for example:

```
{ "0-1":
  [ [ { date: "2009-01-01".
        id: null,
        level: "0.08"
      }
    ],
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
}
```

I want to skip having all the arrays of length one and just have the object stored there.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of the input you're dealing with and the output you want?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can fix the immediate issue by replacing this line:

```
var levels = _.map(_.pluck(points, "level"), parseFloat);
```

With this:

```
var levels = _.map(_.pluck(points[0], "level"), parseFloat);
```

...but I think the real problem might be that you're doing `groupBy` twice when you don't need to. This single `groupBy` ought to be equivalent, but without the extra nested array:

```
var groupedLevels = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
  var dateParsed = parseDate(item.date);
  var month = dateParsed.getMonth();
  var day = dateParsed.getDate();
  return month + '-' + day;
});
```

With this, your `each` should work as expected.